# Set up and install non play store apps to multiple devices?

Tags: installation

I set up roughly 10 android tablets running version 4.4.2 a day, running through set up manually, customizing the settings and downloading an .apk and setting that up.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to run through all this, whether it's a software that could allow me to remote control all of them at once since they all go through the exact same steps, using a script or anything really?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There won't be a one-stop solution for your need because the devices you set up obviously won't be rooted, and so, restrictions are so many to overcome. You may take a look at [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) or the very  popular guide namely  [Full backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) (it tells you to restore as well).

Comment: @Firelord the last link is the correct starter – fine-tuned in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is something to make your task easier – though not in the way of "remote control all of them at once", but working sequentially. Here's a "simple approach":

1. Prepare your first device (let's call it "master" here): install all the apps you want to have it, set them up if needed.
2. Create a full ADB backup of the "master" (for details, please see [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575))
3. Now, for each device, restore that "master backup"

This should definitely work, but with a few restrictions:

- it works best if all devices are of the same brand and model, running the same Android version. It *might* work for devices not fitting (all) these criteria, but then special care must be taken (e.g. better not include "system stuff")
- limitations come up concerning some data, such as SMS, which are protected against being backed up (don't ask me why)
- limitations apply to apps protecting themselves against backups (by setting the `ALLOW_BACKUP` flag to `FALSE` in their manifests)

You might be able to work around the latter two limitations by rooting the "master", installing the *Xposed Framework*, and use the [Backup All Apps](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.backupallapps) module. You then would need to fine-tune step 2 to have the backup only include the packages you want (i.e. explicitly specify/include them on the command line).

Comment: Always glad to help, Taylor! If you like it, please don't forget to upvote it – and if you consider it a solution, consider "accepting" it (ticking the check-mark next to the answer) so others with a similar issue can see it worked out for you (that's how this site works ;). Thanks a lot, and enjoy!